# SQL query for Length and Between

Tags: mysql

I need to write a query for finding the length of the word between `value1` and `value2`. I tried the query below:

```
select * from table_name where LENGTH (column_name (BETWEEN 1 and 2) );
```

Comment: You want the length or filter by the name ?

Comment: First add a column that pulls the length value correctly. Then use that column definition in the where clause.

Comment: Can you describe the statement bit more? The statement is unclear

Comment: i need length of a word in a column1 which is between value1 and value2

Comment: `SELECT LENGTH(col_name) AS len FROM table_name HAVING len BETWEEN( 1 AND 2);`?

Comment: @malk, My requirement is to find the words in a column whose length in between X and Z...

Comment: I get it, but you are not pulling the length properly. First things first.

Comment: Thanks BenM , it worked here it is.... select * , LENGTH (column_name) as len from table_name HAVING len BETWEEN 0 and 8;

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE LENGTH (column_name) BETWEEN 1 and 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will select all rows where `col_name` has a length between `1` and `5`:

```
 SELECT table_name.*, 
       LENGTH(col_name) AS len 
   FROM table_name 
 HAVING len 
BETWEEN( 1 AND 5 );
```

You could also use [`CHAR_LENGTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) or [`CHARACTER_LENGTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_character-length) if needed. Please note that [`LENGTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_length) will give you the number of bytes the string occupies (when using multi-byte charsets at least).

Be sure you absolutely need EVERYTHING (i.e. `*`) from the table, though -- that's very rarely the case.